# Why does subprocess.popen behave differently as a single statement?

Tags: python, python-2.7

When attempting a subprocess.Popen call to get the return code of a command, I get different results depending on whether I break the call up into distinct statements or not. I'm not tied up on making it work as a single statement anymore, but I am not able to articulate why this is the case and want to know more (if it's possible to get a single statement then obviously all the better).

What I wanted to do was the following:

```
my_variable = subprocess.Popen(
  'ip addr show ens192 | grep master',
  shell=True).communicate().returncode
```

Which yields:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'returncode'
```

However when I take the same logic and break it across several lines, it works:

```
>>> my_variable = subprocess.Popen('ip addr show ens192 | grep master', shell=True)
>>> my_variable.communicate()
(None, None)
>>> my_variable.returncode
1
>>>
```

Why is this? This is not behavior I'm used to with Python and I am guessing it has something to do with how it is running the command under the hood.

Comment: You assign totally different things to your variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`returncode` is an attribute of `Popen`, not of the tuple returned by `communicate()`.

Therefore `my_variable.returncode` works, because `my_variable` is the `Popen` instance.

On the other hand `subprocess.Popen(...).communicate().returncode` doesn't work, because, while `subprocess.Popen(...)` is the `Popen` instance, `subprocess.Popen(...).communicate()` evaluates to a tuple `(None, None)` returned by `communicate`, not the `Popen` instance it was called on.
The tuple does not have an attribute `returncode` as the error message tells you.

Your problem is merely a confusion of what `communicate()` returns. It does not return the `Popen` instance that it was called on. This is not an issue of the inner workings or semantics of `Popen`.